# IQKeyBoardManager : Hide keyboard for a specific textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iqkeyboardmanager

In my app I have a form where the user fills out his/her information, the form has some textfields and amongst those is one where the user can select their country. This textfiled is a dropdown which when active displays a dropdown (tableview) with the list of countries to select. I have created a demo project, to reproduce the issue and share it here.
In this demo, I have add 3 textfields, when the user goes to the second textfiled, using the `next` button on the keyboard, a tableview is displayed. Now what I want to achieve is my keyboard should hide when the dropdown tableview is displayed.
I have put in quite some time trying to figure this out but has no success.
Here is the link to the demo project:
https://github.com/tejaskutal/IQKeyboardManagerDemo

Any help is greatly appretiated.

P.S: For some weird reason, when you click `next` when the first textfiled is active, it jumps to the third one first and then goes to second textfield after `next` is clicked one more time. However, this has nothing to do with the original problem so I left it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to handle different delegate. In your `viewDidload` you can do something like,

```
 yourTextField.inputView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
 yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

so, for that textfield keyboard or toolbar will not be appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `UITextField`'s delegate and implement the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. Something like

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == theTextFieldToIgnore {
            view.endEditing(true)
            return false
        }
}
```

As for your textField chaining, you should implement the `textFieldShouldReturn`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == firstOne {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            secondOne.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: If I add `return false` in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing ` the keyword will not be shown for any textfield, right ?

Comment: @TejasK Yes indeed. You should use a check for that in your code, I updated my code as well. :)

Comment: Hi, I tried this, however this does not dismiss the keyboard shown due to the previous textfield. Request you to check the code on GitHub.

Comment: Ok updated the code. I just made a few incorrect assumptions. `view.endEditing(true)` will dismiss any previously open keyboard.

Comment: No `[self.view endEditing:YES]` is not dismissing the keyboard, that's what my problem is :(

Answer (score -1):

Return key Action which textfield you want to resign

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [self.yourTf resignFirstResponder];

}
```